# What is the growth rate of the sum of powers of distinct primes closest to a given a integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and
$$2 = p_1 < p_2 < \dots < p_m \le n$$
be the sequence of all primes less than or equal to $n$.

For each index $j$ let $p_j^{e_j}$ be the largest power of $p_j$ still less than or equal to $n$.
Define

$$S_n = p_1^{e_1} + p_2^{e_2} + \dots + p_{m}^{e_m} $$

to be the sum of these prime powers. What is the growth rate of this series $S_n$?

We can get an upper bound of

$$S_n \le nm \sim \frac{n^2}{\ln n}$$

by the prime number theorem, and a lower bound of

$$S_n \ge \lfloor n/p_1\rfloor + \lfloor n/p_2\rfloor + \dots + \lfloor n/p_m\rfloor \sim n\ln \ln n $$

using the fact that each term $p_j^{e_j}$ is within a factor of $p_j$ of $n$ and asymptotics for the sum of the reciprocals of the primes.

However, there's still some gap between these two bounds. Is the precise asymptotic growth rate of $S_n$ known?

Comment: If you just pick the primes bigger than n/2, that sum gets you close to the upper bound.  You can improve upon this by taking the sum of all primes bigger than square root of n to get close to optimal.  There will still be uncertainty of size sqrt(n)lnln n/in n, unless you do some hard work. Gerhard "Like Some Really Serious Arithmetic" Paseman, 2020.08.10.

Comment: Perhaps one can try to figure out the index $j$ that maximizes the quantity $n-p_{j}^{e_{j}}$ to refine the aforementioned bounds.

Comment: Also, the quantities $\delta_{j}:=n-p_{j}^{e_{j}}$ must be all different, so you can get this way a new upper bound $nm-m(m-1)/2$.

Comment: Would this be related to Sylvester Schur theorem? Gerhard "Is Really Interested In Motivation" Paseman, 2020.08.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better lower bound is $S(n)$, the sum of all primes below $n$, and this lower bound makes a good asymptotic value.  One can tweak this by observing that for every term corresponding to a prime less than $\sqrt{n}$ that term is at least $n^{2/3}$, so a tighter lower bound like $S(n) - S(\sqrt{n}) + n^{7/6}/\log n$ is available. Since $S(n)$ is like $O(n^2/\log n)$, one wonders how good an asymptotic is desired.

Gerhard "Wonders What This Is For" Paseman, 2020.08.10.

Comment: As observed in another comment thread, we have S(n) + O(n^{3/2}/\log n) as an upper bound, so there is not much room for improvement.  Gerhard "Unless The Application Needs It?" Paseman, 2020.08.10.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer for now.
Denote by $M$ the quantity $\max\{n-p_{j}^{e_{j}}\}$. Then $nm-m(m-1)/2\geq S_{n}\geq nm-M-(M-1)-(M-2)-\cdots\geq nm-mM+m(m-1)/2$. So determining $M$ would get us closer to the real order of growth of $S_{n}$.

Edited after Gerhard's contributions: let now $x_n$ be the solution of $x_n=\frac{\log n}{\log x_n}$. Then a lower bound for $S_{n}$ is $\sum_{p\leq x_{n}}p^{\lfloor\frac{\log n}{\log p}\rfloor}+S(n)-S(x_n)$ but this must be difficult to estimate.

Comment: Unfortunately M is almost n minus sqrt(n), so this will lead to a poor estimate.  Better to just take sum of primes below n.  Gerhard "But Many Have Same Parity" Paseman, 2020.08.10.

Comment: Kinda curiously one has $S_{100}=1230=\pi(100^2)+1$. So maybe one can expect to have $S_{n}\sim \frac{n^{2}}{2\log n}$.

Comment: Indeed, one has that already using S(n) as a lower bound  (as in my posted answer), and the poster's sum differs from that by less than n^3/2.  Gerhard "The Powers Aren't Very Powerful" Paseman, 2020.08.10.

Comment: Also $x_n$ is the "square root for tetration" of $n$, so this might provide a "natural" explanation for the factor $1/2$ as "tetration power" (which I admit is extremely speculative).

Comment: For $n=100$, the error between $S_n$ and my lower bound is around $\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{n}\log n$, which is, up the implied constant, the error term for the PNT under RH.

Comment: Yes, but log 100 and sqrt 100 are not that far off.  If you set x_n to sqrt n you will get better results for larger values of n.  Gerhard "Avoid Small Problems Getting Big" Paseman , 2020.08.10.

Comment: I saw your other post relating to this one. While your quantity there may be of some theoretical interest, really using sqrt n for x_n gives you a tighter result, and although you have more powers to approximate, you can still do some good estimates of the subsum.  Gerhard "Really, Go With The Root" Paseman, 2020.08.10.